# How to find combination of tag and text in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've scraped HTMl from a website and need to obtain a particular tag within it, problem is, it is formatted in a confusing way and I cannot obtain the entire tag. Let me illustrate:

```
data = """
<div class="Answer">
1. BOUNDARIES - EPB &amp; APL&nbsp;<i>(inferior)</i>, EPL&nbsp;<i>(superior).&nbsp;</i><div>2. FLOOR (proximal to distal) - radial styloid =&gt; scaphoid =&gt; trapezium =&gt; 1st MC base.&nbsp;<br /><div>3. CONTENTS - cutaneous branches of radial nerve&nbsp;<i>(on the roof),</i>&nbsp;cephalic vein&nbsp;<i>(begins here),</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;radial artery&nbsp;<i>(on the floor).</i></div></div><div><br /></div><div><img src="paste-27a44c801f0776d91f5f6a16a963bff67f0e8ef3.jpg" /><br /></div><div><b>Image:&nbsp;</b>Case courtesy of Dr Sachintha Hapugoda, &lt;a href="https://radiopaedia.org/"&gt;Radiopaedia.org&lt;/a&gt;. From the case &lt;a href="https://radiopaedia.org/cases/52525"&gt;rID: 52525&lt;/a&gt; [Accessed 15 Nov. 2018].</div>
</div>
"""
```

From the above, I wish to obtain only this:

```
<div><b>Image:&nbsp;</b>Case courtesy of Dr Sachintha Hapugoda, &lt;a href="https://radiopaedia.org/"&gt;Radiopaedia.org&lt;/a&gt;. From the case &lt;a href="https://radiopaedia.org/cases/52525"&gt;rID: 52525&lt;/a&gt; [Accessed 15 Nov. 2018].</div>
```

I wrote the following code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
image_link = soup.find('div').find('b').next.next
print(image_link)
```

But it only gets me the text:

```
Case courtesy of Dr Sachintha Hapugoda, <a href="https://radiopaedia.org/">Radiopaedia.org</a>. From the case <a href="https://radiopaedia.org/cases/52525">rID: 52525</a> [Accessed 15 Nov. 2018].
```

How do I get the entire tag?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe try:

```
image_link = soup.find('div').find('img').next.next
```

**Output**:

```
<div><b>Image: </b>Case courtesy of Dr Sachintha Hapugoda, &lt;a href="https://radiopaedia.org/"&gt;Radiopaedia.org&lt;/a&gt;. From the case &lt;a href="https://radiopaedia.org/cases/52525"&gt;rID: 52525&lt;/a&gt; [Accessed 15 Nov. 2018].</div>
```